# How to display random numbers (and colours) for a Roulette Wheel?

Tags: c, random

Have to create a Roulette Wheel in C for coursework, trying to generate random numbers and have the program state the colour of the random number it selects (e.g. chooses 3 and program gives an output saying the selected pocket is red). I've made a small program, which doesn't work too well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int random_number(int min_num, int max_num);

int main(void) {

    printf("Landed on pocket %d\n",random_number(0,36));
      return 0;
    }

    int random_number(int min_num, int max_num)
    {
        int result=0,low_num=0,hi_num=0;
        if(min_num<max_num)
        {
            low_num=min_num;
            hi_num=max_num+1; // this is done to include max_num in output.
        }else{
            low_num=max_num+1;// this is done to include max_num in output.
            hi_num=min_num;
        }
        srand(time(NULL));
        result = (rand()%(hi_num-low_num))+low_num;


    scanf ("%d", &result);

    if (result == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 9 || 12 || 14 || 16 || 18|| 19 || 21 || 23 || 25 || 27 || 30 || 32 || 34 || 36) 
    {           
        printf (" Red \n");

    }    
    else
    {
        if(result == (2|| 4|| 6|| 8|| 10|| 11|| 13|| 15|| 17|| 20|| 22|| 24|| 26|| 28|| 29|| 31|| 33|| 35))
        printf (" Black ");
        }

        return result;
 }
```

I'm fairly new at programming and would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Please be specific - what exactly "doesn't work too well"?

Comment: Wait, "result == 1 || 3 " is not doing what you think it does. Only the first is a comparison between a variable and a constant. The rest will probably be interpreted as a truth value. It would have to be result == 1 || result == 3, which is tedious and error prone. They are uneven numbers? So they are not divisible by 2. if ((result % 2) == 1) for example (r mod 2 = rest is 1)

Comment: The colours are not random on a Roulette  wheel - they are either black or red, except for zero that is green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of use of `||` operator is completely wrong. You should rather use `switch` here:

```
switch( result) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    // and so on...
    case 34:
    case 36:
        printf( "Red");
        break;
    default:   // otherwise
        printf( "Black");
        break;
}
```

**EDIT**

Operator `||` is a 'logical OR' – it takes two `int` operands and returns 1 if at least one of the operands is 'true' (which in case of integer values means 'non-zero') and returns 0 if both are zero. Its precedence is lower than that of comparision operator `==`, so the first of your conditional expressions

```
result == 1 || 3 || ... || 36
```

is calculated as

```
(result == 1) || (3 || (... || 36))
```

The comparision returns either 1 or 0, depending on the `result` value. Anyway 'logically OR-ed' with 3 that gives 1 ('true') and that result propagates through the rest of an expression. That's why the first `if` is always satisfied and the program result is always "Red".

On the other hand the second `if` would compare the `result` to the logical sum of several non-zero numbers – that is, to 1. Which is, of course, completely different from what you intended.

If you really want to write those conditions with `||` you need this form:

```
if(result == 1 || result == 3 || ... || result == 36)

if(result == 2 || result == 4 || ... || result == 35)
```

But the `switch` instruction is much more readable.

Another way would be preparing a static array to translate the `result`. This might seem mysterious a bit, however it is the fastest way to achieve the result desired:

```
static const int ColorCode[37] = {
    0,                    // zero green
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ... // red and black
    2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1};    // black and red

int color = ColorCode[ result];
switch( color) {
    case 0: printf( "Green"); break;
    case 1: printf( "Red");   break;
    case 2: printf( "Black"); break;
}
```

Comment: You should add why it's "wrong". It will be much more helpful for the OP

Comment: @lethal-guitar Yes, I know, alas had not enough time. May be in a next half an hour...

Comment: @lethal-guitar: More wxplanation added, as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?  Recall that: In number ranges from 1 to 10 and 19 to 28, odd numbers are red and even are black. In ranges from 11 to 18 and 29 to 36, odd numbers are black and even are red. 0 and 00 are green.

```
if( ( ( (result>=1  && result<=10) || (result>=19 && result<=28) ) && result%2==1) ||
    ( ( (result>=11 && result<=18) || (result>=29 && result<=36) ) && result%2==0 ) ) {
    printf (" Red \n");
}
else if( result == 0 ) { // doesn't account for double 0 though!
    printf (" Green \n");
}
else {
    printf (" Black \n");
}
```

Comment: Add "00" to the set by increasing the range of random numbers by 1; if it is "37", print "00, green, *partage*; faites vos jeux s'il vous plait" instead.